# IoT simulation using NS3

Tags: simulation, iot, ns-3

how can I use NS3 to simulate IoT, is there some model that should be added?
I'm studying RPL protocol security, and I found that the simulation could be done using NS3, but I don't know is there a model specific to IoT.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Currently, LR-WPAN (IEEE 802.15.4) module is available in ns3, which is one of the IoT technologies. You can use RPL in Tree or/and mesh typologies due to the RPL nature. Also, LoRaWAN module is available for ns3 (you can find on github), which is also IoT technology. However, LoRaWAN currently supports star of star topology. If you extend it to multi-hop, then you can use RPL as routing protocol in LoRaWAN.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, is there some guidance or links that can help me with that , since I'm a beginner with ns3

Answer (score -1):

LoRaWAN ns-3 extension can be used to simulate IoT Networks.
This is an ns-3 module that can be used to perform simulations of a LoRaWAN network. This module was developed by Davide Magrin and Martina Capuzzo of the Signet Lab at University of Padova’s Department of Information Engineering, under the supervision of Lorenzo Vangelista, Marco Centenaro, Andrea Zanella and Michele Zorzi.

The following is the NetAnim output of one such simulated mobile IoT scenario.

LoRaWAN Mobile IoT network Simulation:
[image: LoRaWAN IoT network Simulation]

[Simulation and Analysis of IoT LoRaWAN Networks Under ns-3](https://www.projectguideline.com/simulation-and-analysis-of-iot-lorawan-networks-under-ns-3/)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)